# Higher Order Functions - Eloquent JS

Tags: javascript

I have been reading through Chapter 5 last night and throughout the morning and can't seem to get the higher order functions concepts to stick.  Here are the examples:
     //I understand this first function, I am including it because it is used in the next function.

```
function forEach(array, action) {
 for (vari = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  action(array[i]);

}
forEach(["Wampeter", "Foma", "Granfalloon"], print);

function sum(numbers) {
  var total = 0;
  forEach(numbers, function(number) {
   total += number;
});

return total;

}
```

To my understanding the function sum is taking the argument numbers, which I believe comes in as an array? Now, when the forEach function is called (within sum), it takes the array numbers passed to sum and then it also takes an anonymous function?

I am really confused on what this anonymous function is actually doing.  It is taking the parameter number but what else is it doing?  Does this anonymous function imply that in that parameter, a function like print or show will be passed the parameter number? In other words it would look something like this

```
function([10,12,11]) {
  var total = 0
 forEach([10,12,11]), show(???)
//at this point it would iterate over the array, and use the action passed to display        `//the pointer in the array.  What I think is happening is that it is taking this pointer value and adding it to the total.` //
```

I have been trying to wrap my head around this example for a while, if anyone knows of a good explanation or any other documentation to read over I would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anonymous function is applied to **every currently selected element**. You can *see* better how this works if you *unroll* (execute stepwise) the loop (pseudocode, * means current element):

```
var total = 0;
forEach([*1, 2, 3]), fun(1)) => total = 0 + 1 = 1
forEach([1, *2, 3]), fun(2)) => total = 1 + 2 = 3
forEach([1, 2, *3]), fun(3)) => total = 3 + 3 = 6
```

You can rewrite the **sum** function like this:

```
// because there is no "pass by reference" in JavaScript for
// "simple" types, total must be wrapped in an object
// in order to return the sum through the parameter for the showcase
var result = { total: 0 }
function sum(numbers_array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers_array.length; i++) {
        accumulate(result, numbers_array[i]); 
    }
}

function accumulate(acc, number) {
    acc.total += number;
}
```

In this case the accumulate function does the same as the anonymous function. When the **accumulate** function is declared within the scope of the **sum** function, then the **total** variable is like global (it is known) to the accumulate function and then there is no need of the first parameter, so the function becomes like the one you already know:

```
var total = 0;
function sum(numbers_array) {
    function accumulate(number) {
        total += number;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < numbers_array.length; i++) {
        accumulate(numbers_array[i]); 
    }
}
```

Next step would be to extract and pass the accumulate function as parameter:

```
var total = 0;

function accumulate(number) {
   total += number;
}
// notice, that JavaScript knows how many parameters your function expects
function sum(numbers_array, action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers_array.length; i++) {
        action(numbers_array[i]); 
    }
}
```

What left is to extract the iteration and the code will look like this one in the book.

Comment: Great explanation and code snippets.  That helped me visualize what is going on.  Thanks @pasty!

Comment: Glad that it helped. It's always a good start to break things down to smaller steps in order to see how they work.

Answer (score 2):

Let me see if I can explain this easily for you:

The `forEach()` function accepts two parameters, the first one called `array` is obviously an array or an array-like object, the second parameter called `action` is actually a function.

`forEach()` visits each element in the array passed to it and applies to each element in the array the function passed to it as the second parameter.

So `forEach()` calls the function passed to it named `action` for each element in the array and it gives the function the array element as a parameter.

The function `sum(numbers)` accepts an array as you have though, and it uses `forEach()` inside itself to calculate the sum of numbers in that array using the anonymous function.

Remeber that the anonymous function is called once for each element in the array passed to `sum()` so it actually sums the elements in the array.

Comment: Not sure who down voted.  This was a spot on explanation.  Thanks @sniffer

Answer (score 0):

In simple words : to make your code more generic and concise.

Ex: 
  Lets say we want to find the max element in an Array :
  That's pretty easy and cool :
  In java script we will write :

```
var array = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
function maxEle(array){
  var max = array[0];
  for(var i=0;i< array.length;i++){
    if(max < array[i]){
      max = array[i];
     }
  }
  console.log(max);     
}
```

So this will give me the maximum element in an array.

Now after few days, some one asked me that your max is working pretty cool, I want a function which will print the minimum in an array.
Again I will redo the same thing, which i was doing in finding Max.

```
function minEle(array){
  var min = array[0];
  for(var i=0;i< array.length;i++){
    if(min > array[i]){
      min = array[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(min);     
}
```

Now this is also working pretty cool.
After sometime, another requirement comes up : I want a function which will print the sum of all the elements of the array.

Again the code will be similar to what we have written till now, except now it will perform summation.

```
 function sumArr(array){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0;i< array.length;i++){
     sum = sum + array[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(sum);     
 }
```

**Observation** :
After writing these bunch of codes, I m rewriting almost the same thing in every function, iterating over the Array and then performing some action.
Now writing the repetitive code is not a cool stuff.
Therefore we will try to encapsulate the varying part i.e action viz min, max, summation.
Since its feasible to pass functions as arguments to a function in FPL.
therefore we will re-factor our previously written code and now write a more generic function.

```
var taskOnArr = function(array, task){
   for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
     task(array[i]);
   }
}
```

Now this will be our generic function, which can perform task on each element of Array.

Now our tasks will be :

```
var maxEle = array[0];
var taskMaxEle = function(ele){
   if(maxEle < ele){
      maxEle = ele;
   }
 }
```

Similarly for min element :

```
var minEle = array[0];
var taskMinEle = function(ele){
   if(minEle > ele){
     minEle = ele;
   }
}
```

Also for summation of Array :

```
var sum = 0;
var taskSumArr = function(ele){
   sum = sum + ele;
}
```

Now we need to pass functions to taskOnArr function :

```
taskOnArr(array,taskSumArr);
console.log(sum);

taskOnArr(array,taskMinEle);
console.log(minEle);

taskOnArr(array,taskMaxEle);
console.log(maxEle);
```